# extract the top values from one column based on another column

Tags: python

so basically I have this dataframe called df:

[image: dataframe]

where the first column have list of user id and the genre that they played and the total number of them. how can I extract the top 10 genres with most streams while showing the total number of users who streamed them?

so what I thought of doing is to sort the column values like this:

```
df_genre.sort_values(by="total_streams",ascending=False)
```

and then get the top genre but I got this:

[image: result]

But this is not what i want how can i fix it?

Comment: have you tried `.grouby()` to group by the genre and then sum of total number? Also, can you please edit your post to not share images of data but post code snippets of the actual data and expected output?

Comment: Please edit your post to match a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that other can copy your data and suggests solutions.

Comment: @tylerjames I tried but I think i've done it wrong cz I did not get a good result

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

Data:

```
ID,genre,plays
12345,pop,23
12345,pop,576
12345,dance,18
12345,world,45
12345,dance,23
12345,pop,456
```

Input:

```
df = df.groupby(['ID','genre'])['plays'].sum().reset_index()
df.sort_values(by=['plays'], ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
    ID      genre   plays
1   12345   pop     1055
2   12345   world   45
0   12345   dance   41
```